# Stringer equivalent for json marshal

Tags: go

I can implement `Stringer` to specify how `fmt.Print()` will write my custom type as a string. Is there an equivalent for json marshal?

I want to store unique values in go and represent it as a slice in json. Using a slice in go isn't optimal for this. This O(n) insert seems unnecessary - a binary tree or map would be faster, specially since I'm keeping the list sorted at all times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, [`json.Marshaler`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) and [`json.Unmarshaler`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler).

Implementing `MarshalJSON` and `UnmarshalJSON` will give you what you want.